# Fast pseudorandom number generator for cryptography in C

Tags: c++, c, random, cryptography

I was using the following code to generate sequence of pseudo-random numbers that was used for cryptographic purposes, but then I read somewhere that it may not be very secure. Can someone give me C implementation of a better generator -- the main goal is for this method to be fast. For instance, I did some research and came across [Blum Blum Shub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum_Blum_Shub) method, which would totally kill performance by doing pow(N) calculations.

PS. And please don't quote Wikipedia articles w/o C/C++ code. I'm looking for C or C++ code sample of what I'm showing below.

```
#define ROL(v, shift) ((((v) >> ((sizeof(v) * 8) - (shift))) | ((v) << (shift))))

ULONGLONG uiPSN = doSeed();   //64-bit unsigned integer

for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
{
    uiPSN = uiPSN * 214013L + 2531011L;
    uiPSN = ROL(uiPSN, 16);

    //Apply 'uiPSN'
}
```

Comment: I strongly advise using a PRNG that supports either Hash-DRBG or HMAC-DRBG, especially if you have any intention on FIPS certification. The algorithms and their requirements are available on the [NIST website](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-90A/SP800-90A.pdf), and they are *not* trivial (good security rarely is).

Comment: [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) is a good balance between speed and "randomness". Many open-source implementations exist for many languages. You can download a `C++` implementation [here](http://www.bedaux.net/mtrand/)

Comment: @awashburn Or use `<random>`'s implementation which is in the standard.

Comment: @Rapptz I haven't familiarized myself with the C++ standard libraries yet. If a Mersenne Twister implementation exists int he `random` namespace, use that!

Comment: @awashburn [it does](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine).

Comment: @awashburn As the Wikipedia page notes, the Mersenne Twister is no good for *cryptographic* uses.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Wow, dude it's 128 pages. A quick search returns this C code: http://benpfaff.org/writings/clc/prng.c Could it be close to it?

Comment: Never, ever try to invent your own cryptography. (Unfortunately, there are only two kinds of programmers in the world: Those who don't need to be told this, and those who won't listen when told.)

Comment: @Nemo: I did not invent it. It is C's `rand` implementation.

Comment: @c00000fd if you're asking if that is close to compliance with Hash-DRGB or HMAC-DRBG I would say no, just looking at the size of the codebase. These algorithms require digest engines and a whole lot of very specific operations. As I said, it doesn't matter if you're not needing FIPS compliant crypto (which you should, but that is another matter). The point of hash-based PRNGs is the impossibility of reversing the hash. (and yeah, its a little huge, ain't it?) =)

Comment: @c00000fd I think Nemo was talking about whatever you'd built on top of whatever RNG you end up using. And I fear he's right.

Comment: @WhozCraig: OK. I'm trying to find a C/C++ implementation of Hash-DRBG and so far all I get is a bunch of lengthy articles and no code. Don't get me wrong, I like reading math formulas, but it's way easier for me to understand C/C++ code...

Comment: You cannot use an ordinary random number generator for cryptographic applications. Even those with excellent statistical properties are useless against any attacker more sophisticated than a bright child. A **cryptographic** RNG is a special beast. Although @delnan is right, I am also worried about whatever you are planning to do with these pseudo-random numbers. The #1 rule of cryptography is to use somebody else's design. The #2 rule of cryptography is to use somebody else's implementation.

Comment: @Nemo: I appreciate your concern. But if we apply your rules there'll be no cryptography out there...

Comment: The number of people who think they are exceptions to these rules is around 100 times the number of people who actually are. Unless you have made a career out of it, you are almost certainly not qualified to design nor to implement cryptographic code. Take a look at the 10 [most recent vulnerabilities](http://www.openssl.org/news/vulnerabilities.html) in OpenSSL. If you can convince yourself that you would not have made any of those mistakes, great. If not, do yourself and your users a favor and _use somebody else's code_.

Comment: @Nemo: OK, I'm not into arguing with you. You're basically saying that there's no perfect cryptography and every encryption can be broken with a sufficient amount of time and effort. And I agree with that. I'm looking for a simpler and mostly faster solution here...

Comment: @c00000fd: Why are you so adamant about getting the code? The point of programming is to make it yourself. Also, fast and cryptographically secure are almost always at odds. Find something that *works* (is cryptographically secure), then worry about *speed* (a nicety that is useless of the code doesn't work).

Comment: As a cryptographer, please find a certified off the shelf library...

Comment: @c00000fd No one ever accused the NIST of being brief.

Comment: @brianbeuning LOL. After all the time I spent pouring over their standards, drafts, and addendum, "brief" seriously made me shoot soda out of my nose. Thanks for the laugh.

Comment: For reference for those users who came here and don't know a lot of cryptography here is an excellent course: https://www.coursera.org/course/crypto/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

ISAAC (http://www.burtleburtle.net/bob/rand/isaacafa.html) is probably one of the fastest cryptographically secure PRNGs (code at site). Another approach is to use a block cipher in counter mode. Something like TwoFish, which is reasonably fast and freely available, would be effective.

If you don't need a lot of numbers, all modern operating systems have built-in RNGs suitable for cryptographic use, though they typically can't produce lots of numbers because they rely on accumulating entropy from sources like input timings. Unix-like systems (Linux, OSX) have /dev/random, Windows has CryptGenRandom. Even if these aren't suitable for your needs, you probably should use them to seed the PRNG you do end up using.

Comment: Now there's also Cha-cha to consider.

Answer (score 6):

Look at (or use) the random number generator in the OpenSSL library.

The hard part with any secure random number generator is the seeding.
If you are on Windows, consider using rand_s().
On Linux look at /dev/urand.

Some seeding methods suffer from not being very random soon after a reboot.
You can make a file with random bytes.
Use the file and the OS method for seeding.
Periodically use your random number generator to write a new file.

Answer (score 1):

Don't "roll your own" cryptography. Use a certified library instead.

For speed, try using a library that can run on the GPU, which has far more computing power.

Answer (score -5):

I would recommend the Mersenne-Twister, which I have used time and again.

The C code is [here](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/VERSIONS/C-LANG/c-lang.html).

If you use C++11, you have mersenne twister as a part of the library itself. Mersenne Twister is currently one of the best algorithms out there.

Here is how I would implement in C++11, as a function. It is very straightforward. the mt19937 is th built in Mersenne Twister in C++11.

```
 std::vector<double> classname::mersennetwister(const int& My,const int& Mz,const int& Ny,const int& Nz)
{
int ysize = (My + 2*Ny + 1);
int zsize = (Mz + 2*Nz + 1);
int matsize = ysize*zsize;
unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
std::mt19937_64 generator (seed);
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0,1);
std::vector<double> randarray = f.array1dgen(matsize,0);
for (int i=0;i<matsize;++i)
{
   randarray[i] = distribution(generator);
}
return(randarray);
}
```

Comment: Wikipedia on disadvantages of MT: "The algorithm in its native form is not suitable for cryptography (unlike Blum Blum Shub). Observing a sufficient number of iterations (624 in the case of MT19937, since this is the size of the state vector from which future iterations are produced) allows one to predict all future iterations."

Comment: @delnan Maybe he only needs a handful of random numbers, far less then 624 iterations?

Comment: @awashburn Then he'd be fine, obviously. But you can't just *assume* that and recommend a solution that's broken if this (often unreasonable) assumption is not true.

Comment: @awashburn: Yes, I agree 624 iterations are way too few... So my only hope is something like Blum Blum Shub, hah?

Comment: @c00000fd If by "something like" you mean "something which is a [CSPRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator)", then yes, that's by definition what you need.

Comment: MT is not cryptographically secure.

Comment: You should not seed PRNG with time only. Crypto PRNG should be seeded with random value with good entropy for example from true random source.