# Is there a C++11 CSPRNG?

Tags: c++, c++11, random, mersenne-twister

As we know, the Mersenne Twister [is not crytographically secure](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/efaq.html):

> Mersenne Twister is not cryptographically secure. (MT is based on a
>   linear recursion. Any pseudorandom number sequence generated by a
>   linear recursion is insecure, since from sufficiently long subsequencje
>   of the outputs, one can predict the rest of the outputs.)

But many sources, like [Stephan T. Lavavej](//channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) and even [this website](//stackoverflow.com/a/7114482/5287986). The advice is almost always (verbatim) to use the Mersenne Twister like this:

```
auto engine = mt19937{random_device{}()};
```

<sub>They come in different flavors, like using `std::seed_seq` or complicated ways of manipulating `std::tm`, but this is the simplest approach.</sub>

Even though `std::random_device` [is not always reliable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device):

> `std::random_device` may be implemented in terms of an
>   implementation-defined pseudo-random number engine if a
>   non-deterministic source (e.g. a hardware device) is not available to
>   the implementation. In this case each `std::random_device` object may
>   generate the same number sequence.

The `/dev/urandom` vs `/dev/random` debate [rages on](http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/).

But while the standard library provides a good collection of PRNGs, it doesn't seem to provide any CSPRNGs. I prefer to stick to the standard library rather than using POSIX, Linux-only headers, etc. Can the Mersenne Twister be manipulated to make it cryptographically secure?

Comment: To downvoter, how can I improve my question?

Comment: Not downvoter (actually upvoted), but I think you should make the links clickable.

Comment: *Can the Mersenne Twister be manipulated to make it cryptographically secure?* No.

Comment: @dandan78 Ok. I even throw in protocol-less URLs for good measure

Comment: Links were broken since most of them don't work with https. Fixed now

Comment: @DavidHammen The link I used says: "To make it secure, you need to use some Secure Hashing Algorithm with MT. For example, you may gather every eight words of outputs, and compress them into one word (thus the length of the output sequence is 1/8 of the original one)." Can you elaborate or counterpoint?

Comment: Have you see this post?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18323738/fast-pseudorandom-number-generator-for-cryptography-in-c

Comment: @user5287986 The sequence "1 2 3 4 5 6" is almost secure after a Secure Hashing Algorithm (well, not really, because someone might guess that one).  However, start at some unpredictable seed, and do the same, and determining which of `+1` or "apply mt" is more secure would require actual research (the answer might be both, neither, or either one.)  Saying that "applying a secure hash makes it secure" is a bit of a misnomer: the security is independent of the mt.

Comment: Whichever sequence of `mt` calls and hashes you choose to employ, I can pre-compute that sequence offline for every possible seed. Then, I can observe the output of your RNG, compare it to my tables, and figure out the seed you are starting with. After that, I can predict future outputs of your RNG. In other words, applying a deterministic function to a predictable sequence results in a predictable sequence.

Comment: You've probably seen this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator#Designs_based_on_cryptographic_primitives) which mentions: "A cryptographically secure hash of a counter might also act as a good CSPRNG in some cases."

Comment: You may have to implement your own if you want a good CSPRNG. For one example, see the [ISAAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISAAC_(cipher)) cipher.

Comment: @owacoder "implement your own" is almost antithetical to "cryptographically secure"

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - By "implement your own" I meant "use something other than the STL."

Answer (score 6):

Visual Studio guarantees that `random_device` is cryptographically secure and non-deterministic:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982250.aspx

If you want something faster or cross platform, you could for example use GnuTLS: http://gnutls.org/manual/html_node/Random-number-generation.html
It provides random numbers of adjustable quality. `GNUTLS_RND_RANDOM` is what you want I think.

As several people already said, please forget about MT in cryptographic contexts.